# Can you write a cycle as a product of disjoint cycles?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, permutation-cycles

Why do we say "Every permutation on $n$ symbols can be written as a product of disjoint cycles". I see this statement written like that almost everywhere and I think it's slightly incorrect.

For example, let $\sigma \in S_3$ and $\sigma = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 &2 & 3\\ 3 & 1 & 2  \end{matrix}\right)$ then how do you write $\sigma$ as product of disjoint cycles when $\sigma$ is simply a cycle $(1 \ 3 \ 2)$ itself?

I could understand if $\sigma \in S_4$ then you could write it as product of disjoint cycles as $\sigma = (1 \ 3 \ 2 )(4)$ but when it is in $S_3$, there is no product of disjoint cycles.

Am I on the right track? Or is there a way to write a cycle as product of disjoint cycles?

I think it should be something like "Every permutation on $n$ symbols is either a cycle or a product of disjoint cycles", is this correct?

Comment: In these type of general statements it is meant a more general form of product, which could have just one multiplicand or even non(such as the case of the identity permutation), it's a bit like the positive reals sometimes contain 0 and sometimes don't.

Comment: @razivo What do you mean none? Identity permutation is a cycle ($=(1)=(2)= \ldots =(n)$) or product of disjoint cycles ($=(1)(2)\ldots (n)$).

Comment: @razivo Oh do you mean something like an empty product is by definition, an identity? Fair enough but still it doesn't include cases where the permutation is a cycle.

Comment: Oh, right, that isn't a good example, but sometimes it is a product of "zero elements" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: And the product of "one element" covers the single cycle cases.

Comment: disjoint cycles = *if* there is more than one cycle  the elements are disjoint. So for a single cycle it's voidly true.